# How can I calculate the voltage on the load in this circuit?

Tags: voltage, diodes, thevenin

I've been try to solve this circuit for hours and have no idea on how to find the load voltage `U_s`.

[image]

I tried applying the Thevenin theorem to find the equivalent Thevenin voltage (using the voltage divider rule => `E_Th = 6V`) and also the Thevenin resistance (we take `R_s` and `R` in parallel and the result is going to be `5k (ohms)`).

I don't know what to do next. Should I replace the diode with an open circuit because it is reverse biased? After that, is it okay if I say that the voltage on the `cathode` is `V_C = E_0 = 3V`, and compute the voltage on the `anode` using the voltage divider rule?

Comment: Why don't you try using some other analysis technique? Perhaps the node voltage or mesh current method? The first thing you need to figure out **with certainty** is whether or not the diode is forward biased. Do you know how to do that? Prove to yourself one way or the other. We don't hand out homework solutions here so you need to show **all of your work**.

Answer (score 2):

As was suggested in your previous question, redrawing the circuit may help:

[image]

> Thevenin Theorem to find the equivalent Thevenin Voltage (using the Voltage Divider Rule => E_Th = 6V) and also the Thevenin Resistance (we take R_s and R in parallel and the result is going to be 5k (Ohms)).

OK. So that would result in the following circuit:

[image]

From that, what is your reasoning regarding \$I_D\$?

Answer (score 1):

If you move the ground temporarily to the cathode of the diode, you have a Thevenin equivalent of -3V with 5K in series connected to the diode. This is pretty much where you got.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8FHB2.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Obviously, the diode is reverse biased, so for most purposes you can ignore the diode.

Once you have Ud you can easily find Us.

Comment: Spehro, maybe the upside-down voltages in the original circuit caused some confusion?

Comment: @vangelo oops...

Answer (score 0):

Well, let's make a mathematical closed solution. I know that this is maybe above the OP's knowledge, but I think it is important to show it in combination with the other answer given.

The [Shockley diode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shockley_diode_equation), gives the relation between the voltage across and the current trough a diode:

$$\text{I}_\text{D}=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\text{V}_\text{D}}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)\tag1$$

Well, we are trying to analyze the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fok6QQ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

When we use and apply [KCL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirchhoff%27s_circuit_laws#Kirchhoff%27s_current_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$\text{I}_1+\text{I}_2+\text{I}_3=0\tag2$$

When we use and apply [Ohm's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ohm%27s_law), we can write the following set of equations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\text{I}_1=\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_\text{a}}{\text{R}_1}\\
\\
\text{I}_2=\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}\\
\\
\text{I}_3=\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\left(\text{V}_1-\text{V}_2\right)}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)
\end{cases}\tag3
$$

We also know that \$\text{V}_2=-\text{V}_\text{b}\$.

Substitute \$(3)\$ into \$(2)\$, in order to get:

$$\frac{\text{V}_1-\text{V}_\text{a}}{\text{R}_1}+\frac{\text{V}_1}{\text{R}_2}+\text{I}_\text{S}\left(\exp\left(\frac{\text{q}\left(\text{V}_1-\left(-\text{V}_\text{b}\right)\right)}{\eta\text{k}\text{T}}\right)-1\right)=0\tag4$$

For the LED, let's use parameters taken from a Luminus PT-121-B LED: \$\eta=8.37\$, and \$I_\text{SAT}=435.2\:\text{nA}\$. (Assume \$V_T=\frac{\text{kT}}{\text{q}}\approx 25.2617\:\text{mV}\$, of course.)

Using the known values, we find:

- $$\text{V}_1\approx-1.2839\space\text{V}\tag5$$
- $$\text{I}_1\approx-0.00132839\space\text{A}\tag6$$
- $$\text{I}_2\approx-0.00012839\space\text{A}\tag7$$
- $$\text{I}_3\approx0.00145678\space\text{A}\tag8$$

I used Mathematica to find it, with the following code:

```
In[1]:=Clear["Global`*"];
q = ((1602176634/(10^9)))*10^(-19);
k = ((1380649/(10^6)))*10^(-23);
T = 20 + ((5463)/20);
Is = (4352/10)*10^(-9);
\[Eta] = 837/100;
R1 = 10*1000;
R2 = 10*1000;
Va = 12;
Vb = 3;
FullSimplify[
 Solve[{I1 + I2 + I3 == 0, I1 == (V1 - Va)/R1, I2 == V1/R2, 
   I3 == (Is*(Exp[(q*(V1 - (-Vb)))/(\[Eta]*k*T)] - 1)), 
   I1 \[Element] Reals && I2 \[Element] Reals && I3 \[Element] Reals &&
     V1 \[Element] Reals}, {I1, I2, I3, V1}]]

Out[1]={{I1 -> (-46858 - (
    18820282327275 ProductLog[(
      193685353088 E^(801282002353088/18820282327275))/
      18820282327275])/11393256064)/78125000, 
  I2 -> 11723/19531250 - (
    752811293091 ProductLog[(
      193685353088 E^(801282002353088/18820282327275))/
      18820282327275])/35603925200000000, 
  I3 -> (17 (-1 + (
      18820282327275 ProductLog[(
        193685353088 E^(801282002353088/18820282327275))/
        18820282327275])/193685353088))/39062500, 
  V1 -> 93784/15625 - (
    752811293091 ProductLog[(
      193685353088 E^(801282002353088/18820282327275))/
      18820282327275])/3560392520000}}

In[2]:=N[%1]

Out[2]={{I1 -> -0.00132839, I2 -> -0.00012839, I3 -> 0.00145678, 
  V1 -> -1.2839}}
```